# How to make a local extension method avaiable in a function with receiver?

Tags: scope, kotlin, extension-methods

I found an interesting thing, but I couldn't do it. Is there any way to make the local extension method available in a function with receiver.

```
val list = ArrayList<Any>();

fun <T> Array<T>.bind(context: MutableList<in T>, block: Array<T>.() -> Unit) {
    fun Array<T>.save() {
        context.addAll(this);
    }
    block();
}

arrayOf(1, 2, 3).bind(list) {
    save(); //todo: how to bind extension in execution scope
};
```

I know there is an alternative way by introducing another type for the receiver, but I want to avoid it. for example:

```
interface Savable {
    fun save();
}

fun <T> Array<T>.bind(context: MutableList<in T>, block: Savable.() -> Unit) {
    val proxy = object : Savable {
        override fun save() {
            context += this@bind;
        }
    };

    proxy.block();
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you give a use case?

Comment: @KirillRakhman sir. Indeed, this feature is not new, if you familiar with `ruby` . it can add additional methods dynamically into a `object` scope not the `class` scope. let's say we have an `Entity` class, I wish to bind the `CURD` methods into a certain object rather than at the class level.

Comment: Another option may be to pass the save-function as a parameter to `block`.

Comment: @marstran the idea is good, but how to handle when we have more than half dozen extension methods?

Comment: I think you should introduce your interface if you want to do that.

Comment: @marstran yeah, I have already described in my question that I want to avoiding introduce an additional interface for the extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature yet, and I think in near future it won't be added either. **You should just use your second version. Don't care about adding an wrapper class**. The idea of *avoiding introducing a wrapper class* is actually, as long as you are using JVM backend, just **nonsense**, because by using local function you are actually adding a local class.

This is the equivalent Java code of your kotlin function, after fixing as you have suggested, with the assumption that your `bind` function lives in file `bind.kt`:

```
public final class BindKt {
    public static <T> void bind(T[] receiver, List<? super T> context, Function1<T> block) {
        class Local { // the name of local class is unimportant, as it's generated by compiler. It should looks like "package.name.BindKt$bind$X" where X is a number.
            public void save(T[] receiver) {
                context.addAll(receiver);
            }
        }
        block.invoke(this); // this won't compile. Neither will yours.
    }
}
```

As you can see `save` is NOT compiled to a static method, which means, if your `block` somehow ever called that `save`, an instance of `Local` must be fist created. So, no matter what you do, as long as you used a local function, there is basically no point in avoiding introduing a wrapper class. Your second solution is good, and just use it. It's both elegant and efficient enough.

If you really don't want add a class/object creation, move these extension functions to a package scope, and let clients import them.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. but if you replace `C` with `T` and remove the generic parameter `C` in my question, then the code can compile. I know the local extension method is never be used, but I want it available in the lambda scope.

Comment: I added and highlighted some part of the anwser. Please read it carefully. The local extension function should either be moved to a package scope or moved into a wrapper class like your second solution.